# TypeError when fitting surface to 3D scatter data using scipy.optimize.curve_fit()

Tags: python, scipy, typeerror, curve-fitting, scatter3d

I have a Pandas DataFrame with columns containing x, y, and z-values.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': x,
                   'Mileage': y,
                   'Price': z})
```

Using `scipy.optimize.curvefit()` I'm able to fit a univariate exponential function `y = exp(-bx)`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# fit y to x
def exp_function(x, a, b):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(exp_function, df['Age'],    # x-values
                        df['Price'],               # y-values
                        absolute_sigma=False, maxfev=1000)

# popt
# array([2.81641498e+04, 1.29183078e-01])                      # a, b-values
```

But when I try to extend the same analysis to 3D, I encounter a `TypeError`:

```
# fit z to (x, y)
def exp_function_2(x, y, a, b, c):
    return (a/2) * (np.exp(-b * x) + np.exp(-c * y))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(exp_function_2, 
                       df['Age'],           # x-values
                       df['Mileage'],       # y-values
                       df['Price'],         # z-values
                       absolute_sigma=False, maxfev=1000)


# TypeError: exp_function_2() takes 5 positional arguments but 1518 were given
```

Seems like it thinks I'm passing 1518 arguments (the length of my Pandas dataframe) into `exp_function_2()`.

Why does my code work for the 2D `(x, y)` fit but get hung up on the 3D `(x, y, z)` fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the method with the incorrect arguments.

The [docs indicate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) that the prototype is `curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0=None, ...)`, where `p0` is the starting guess for the parameters of your function. So in the case when you have a `TypeError`, you are passing all 1518 elements of your frame as the default parameters to your function, which of course only accepts 5 arguments. The fact that your code works in the 2D case is a happy coincidence of not using the `p0` keyword-argument at all.

You need to pass both the predictors as a single argument in `xdata`, and then unpack them inside the exponential function. Something like this (though I'm not sure I have the dataframe indexing correct, I rarely use pandas):

```
def exp_function_2(x, a, b, c):
    return (a/2) * (np.exp(-b * x['Age']) + np.exp(-c * x['Mileage']))
```